# Sql server select query of with ids, Count of ids grouped by casted date from datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am struggling to find a right way to write as select query that produces a count of ids with unique date, i have Log table as

```
id| DateTime
1|23-03-2019 18:27:45|
1|23-03-2019 18:27:45|
2|23-03-2019 18:27:50|
2|23-03-2019 18:27:51|
2|23-03-2019 18:28:01|
3|23-03-2019 18:33:15|
1|24-03-2019 18:13:18|
2|23-03-2019 18:27:12|
2|23-03-2019 15:27:46|
3|23-03-2019 18:21:58|
3|23-03-2019 18:21:58|
4|24-03-2019 10:11:14|
```

What i have am tried

```
select id, count(cast(DateTime as DATE)) as Counts from Logs group by id
```

its producing proper count of ids with id like

```
id|count
1 | 2|
2 | 3|
3 | 1|
1 | 1|
2 | 2|
3 | 2|
4 | 1|
```

What i want is to add datetime column casted as date

```
id|count|Date
1 | 2| 23-03-2019
2 | 3| 23-03-2019
3 | 1| 23-03-2019
1 | 1| 24-03-2019
2 | 2| 24-03-2019
3 | 2| 24-03-2019
4 | 1| 24-03-2019
```

However i get an error saying

```
Column 'Logs.DateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

when i try

```
    select id, count(cast(DateTime as DATE)) as Counts from Logs group by id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `cast(DateTime as DATE)` also in group by

```
select id,cast(DateTime as DATE) as dateval, count(cast(DateTime as DATE)) as Counts 
from Logs 
group by id,cast(DateTime as DATE)
```

Comment: Wow, that worked out perfectly, guess i never thought we can add multiple group by to a sql statement